# Creating a new user

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, createuser

Hi I am a student new to oracle application express.

I need help in creating a new user. Unfortunately I do not have the option available. I am looking for 'application access control. The screenshot that I will provide does not have that feature.[image]

I have a presentation and I need to make sure that I have proof of showing who can access what. If I can create a new user. I can call them 'staff' then use V('User_app') <> 'staff' to restrict what they can see otherwise. my only option is to use the admin which is me and shw proof through coding that I have done so. but I don't want to do that as I am not sure if it is acceptable. This will be final resort.

what i am looking for should be under security

thanks

Comment: What authentication scheme is your application using?  Are you trying to create an APEX user?  An application user in a custom authentication scheme (which would probably just be an `insert` into a custom `user` table)?  There isn't an option to create a user under Security on that page.  If you are a workspace admin and your application is using APEX users, you could create a new APEX user but I wouldn't expect students in a class to get that level of permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the upper right-hand corner for the icon that looks like a person with a wrench - click that. Do you see the option that says Manage Users and Groups? If you don't see that option, then you are not a Workspace Administrator and will not be able to create new APEX users.

[image]

Comment: no i am not the admin. i have developer role. this  option does not exist. Thank you guys#